vscode: in python, is there a way to know in code if a script is being run with F5 ("Start Debugging") or Ctrl+F5 ("Run Without Debugging")
I run a lot of scripts using VSCode interface and its launch configurations. Since my scripts all produce a lot of artefacts from running, it would be very useful to have an automated way to know if the script is running in debug mode (with F5 in vscode) as oposed to running without debugging (Ctrl+F5 in vscode), so that I could perform some cleanups at the beginning and end of the script's run.
While I could set up a flag for debug mode in my configuration file, an automated way to identify it would be very useful because sometimes I or someone else running the scripts may forget to set the flag.
Is there some way to do that?

You’re making the problem harder than necessary.
Just define a wrapper, and ask VSC to debug that.
def target():
    …

def wrapper():
    cleanup1()
    target()
    cleanup2()


When your debug type is "debugpy" in the config, the debugging can be detected in sys.modules.
launch.json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Module",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "app.main"
        }
    ]
}

app/main.py
def check_is_debug_attached():
    for module in sys.modules.values():
        if module.__name__ == 'debugpy':
            print('Debugger is attached')
            return True

    print('Debugger is not attached')
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    is_debug_attached = check_is_debug_attached()
    print(f'is_debug_attached: {is_debug_attached}')

